# Javascript Sum function return NaN

Tags: javascript

```js
function increase( y) {
    var x = document.getElementById("result");
    var before= x.value;
    x.innerHTML= Number(before) + Number(y);
}
```

```html
<b>Rp. <b id='result'>1240000</b> </b>
<button type="button" onclick="increase(80000)"> add </button>
```

Comment: A `<b>` element doesn't have a `.value`. Use `innerText`.

Comment: it works https://jsfiddle.net/b0kd26oa/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `innerHTML` to get the value of `<b>`.

```js
function increase( y) {
  var x = document.getElementById("result");
  x.innerHTML= parseInt(x.innerHTML) + parseInt(y);
}
```

```html
<b>Rp. <b id="result">1240000</b> </b>
<button type="button" onclick="increase(80000)"> add </button>
```